# Named groups in recursive pattern Match

Tags: regex, perl, recursive-regex

I'm matching on LaTeX-Commands of the form \command{...}{...}. The second argument is optional. My RegEx is a only slightly modificated version of one example in [perl6 faq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#Can-I-use-Perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text%3f) because I need to take care of the case that there may be nested LaTeX commands inside the arguments.

I want to use named groups. How can I do this? I tried to use (?<first>:...) together with (?&first), but it gives me an "infinite recursion" error. I might be a little over my head in terms of RegExes here, but this worked very nicely so far.

```
my $regex = qr/
          \\command
            (\{
              (?:
                [^\{\}]++
                  |
                (?1)
              )*
            \})
           (\{
              (?:
                [^\{\}]++
                  |
                (?2)
              )*
           \})?
        /x;

$s =~ m/$regex/g
```

Comment: Perhaps you can find something useful [here](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=latex)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use named groups like `s/(?<first>foo+)/\k<first>bar/` or `s/(?first:foo+)/\g{first}bar/` but `(?<first>:...)` treats the `:` as part of the pattern.

I'm unsure why your `(?PARNO)` expressions are causing infinite recursion, but the [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) has an extra paren group when doing exactly the same thing.